# Bond > in Functional Group

Tags: mhchem, chemistry

I'd like to get a bond represented by >. As an [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joback_method#Example_Calculation), see the table where the ketone group is represented by >C=O (nonring). Is there a better way to write that other than the following?

```
>\ce{C=O}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Package `mhchem`

`>` can be included inside `\ce` by using math, see section "Using Math, Variables" on page 8 of `mhchem`'s [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mhchem/mhchem.pdf):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}
  \ce{$>$C=O}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result mhchem]

A more complicate version, which works with bold font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}
  \ce{$\hbox{\textgreater}$C=O}
  \textbf{\ce{$\hbox{\textgreater}$C=O}}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result mhchem with bold]

## Package `chemfig`

Package `chemfig` can draw it as (kind of) molecule. Example with different bond lengths:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
  \chemfig{C(-[:150])(-[:210])=O}
  \qquad
  \setatomsep{1.25em}
  \chemfig*{C(-[:150])(-[:210])=O}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result chemfig]

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't see any difference between those. :) Will wait and see if people give other ideas.

Comment: @Bruno Can you explain, what you want to see?

Comment: Your solution is fine. I just didn't see any difference between having the > in math mode or normal text. I think that the vertical alignment could be better in the sense that the tip of the > symbol would be at the same height of of the middle of the C. Maybe I'm being too perfectionist. :)

Comment: Thanks for your addition with the chemfig package. I'm really interested in having the text >C=O inline in a paragraph sentence. So I think it shouldn't look big as in a figure, but part of a sentence.

Comment: @Bruno The greater sign uses the same axis as the double bond, more or less the math axis. I think, `mhchem` provides more or less a text representation for formulas. An other way is shown in the example with `chemfig`, where the molecule is drawn as graphics (`chemfig` is based on TikZ).

Comment: mhchem's bonds are **exactly** on the math axis, because there are also elements with lower case letters. When I decided how far to take mhchem, I stopped at the "2D border". mhchem is only written for 1D. Please notice that with `\ce{$>$C=O}`, the `>` bond it taken from the math font while `=` is taken from the text font. This might not be noticable in the main text, but will be if you put it into a bold heading, for example.

Comment: @mhchem Thanks for the information. I have added a version, which uses the text font version `\textgreater` of the greater sign, which honors a bold font.